# Using Flask Restful as a Blueprint in Large Application

Tags: flask, flask-restful

I am trying to use Flask restful as a Blueprint in a pattern that works for other blueprints. I keep getting the following error message

I get the following error message

> AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'add_resource'

My project setup is as follows:

**Folder structure**

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── routes.py
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   └── templates
│       ├── base.html
│       └── home.html
├── config.py
├── manage.py
└── requirements.txt
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from config import config
bootstrap = Bootstrap()
api = Api()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    api.init_app(app)

    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    from .api import api as api_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(api_blueprint)
    return app
```

**api/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint

api = Blueprint('api', __name__)

from . import routes
```

**api/routes.py**

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from . import api

class TodoItem(Resource):
    def get(self, id):
        return {'task': 'Say "Hello, World!"'}

api.add_resource(TodoItem, '/todos/<int:id>')
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: You have a variable and a package named `api`. I think that's tripping you up. You're importing the `api` blueprint from `api/__init__.py`, not the `api` instance in `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you follow the instructions from https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/intermediate-usage.html

The key points here are to create a Flask Blueprint instance & pass it to a new instance of flask-restfuls's Api class.

Lastly, make sure to register the flask-restful api blueprint within your create_app function: `app.register_blueprint(api_bp)`

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from config import config

bootstrap = Bootstrap()
api_bp = Blueprint('api', __name__)
api = Api(api_bp)

def create_app(config_name):
   app = Flask(__name__)
   app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
   config[config_name].init_app(app)

   bootstrap.init_app(app)

   from .users import main as users_blueprint
   from .blogs import main as blogs_blueprint

   # blueprints for blogs & users
   app.register_blueprint(users_blueprint)
   app.register_blueprint(blogs_blueprint)
   app.register_blueprint(api_bp)
   
   return app
```

Also note, you don't need to register `api.init_app(app)` anymore.

Comment: What if we want to use multiple blueprints with api?

Comment: @darmendarizp I have updated the example to make using multiple blueprints clearer.

Comment: Thanks, but what I meant was, what if we wanted to also do something like `Api(users_blueprint)` and `Api(blogs_blueprint)`? So that every blueprint can use `flask_restful` but with a "single instance of `Api`". I can't find an example for this.

Comment: All your routes, both users & blogs would be using the same instance of the Flask-Restful's API. Using `api` you add all your resources with `add_resource` method:  `api.add_resource(BlogsView)` & `api.add_resource(UsersView)`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have submodules (like **your** /api) based on resources...

**Eg: folder structure**

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── foo
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── routes.py
│   ├── boo
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── routes.py
├── config.py
├── manage.py
```

... and register their blueprints with url_prefix to not repeat the common part in each added resource. Create new Api instance in each module and pass to it a blueprint.

**foo/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint                            
from flask_restful import Api
                                                       
foo_bp = Blueprint('foo', __name__, url_prefix='/foo') 
foo_api = Api(foo_bp)  
                                                                                     
from . import routes
```

in routes import foo_api and add resources to it

**foo/routes.py**

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from . import foo_api

class TodoItem(Resource):
    def get(self, id):
        return {'task': 'Say "Hello, World!"'}

foo_api.add_resource(TodoItem, '/todos/<int:id>')
```

Then in main application __init__.py just import modules blueprints and register it. You dont even need to add a "main" application blueprint. If you would import the api from main application __init__ then you can't register each blueprint with it's own params like url_prefix.

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from config import config

def create_app(config_name):
   app = Flask(__name__)
   app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
   config[config_name].init_app(app)

   from .foo import foo_bp
   from .boo import boo_bp

   app.register_blueprint(foo_bp)
   app.register_blueprint(boo_bp)

   return app
```

You can set the url_prefix on register blueprint (it has priority) or when you create it. To check routes you can print the *app.url_map*

Answer (score 2):

You're running in to trouble because of how you've named your blueprint `api`, whilst also using the `api` object from `flask_restful`. In your `routes.py` you're explicitly importing `api` from `api/__init__.py`, and this is a `Blueprint` object. You can't call `add_resource` to a `Blueprint` object, only to an `Api` object from `flask_restful`.

If you change your import to:

```
from .. import api
```

you'll be importing the correct object. I'd still recommend changing your blueprint name anyway to avoid this sort of confusion.

Comment: Thanks, That fixed the import error, but I get a 404 when i go to /todos/1